# The natural representation of $G=SO(2)$ on $V=\Bbb C^2$ is not irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

**Prove that the natural representation of G=SO(2) on $V=\Bbb C^2$ is not irreducible.**

I proved the following fact which is supposed to be used:

Proposition: Let $G$ a commutative Lie group and $(\pi, V)$ a finite-dim unitary representation of $G$.

(a)  $\pi \text{ is irreducible iff } \dim  V = 1$

(b) There exist mutually orthogonal one dimensional invariant linear subspaces $V_1,..., V_n$ of $V  $ such that $V = V_1 \oplus · · · \oplus V_n$.

**My attempt:**

I assume the natural representation of $ G=SO(2)=\{\,A \in M(n,\Bbb R)\mid \forall x,y \in \Bbb R^2:\left<Ax,Ay\right>=\left<x,y\right>\, \}$ on $V=\Bbb C^2$ is given by:

$$\pi(g):V\to V: v\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & - \sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}v
$$

I can verify the hypotheses of the propositon above:

- $G=SO(2)={M \in O(2)}$ is a commutative Lie group.
- The representation $(V,\pi)$ is finite-dimensional  because $\Bbb C^2$ is finite-dimensional
- The representation $(V,\pi)$ is unitary  because rotations preserve the scalar product on $\Bbb C^2$

So I can use (a) in the proposition to say that because the dim $V=2 \neq 1$ as a $\Bbb C$-vector space, $\pi$ is not irreducible

Is this Okay?

Furthermore I found somewhere that the invariant subspaces are $\Bbb C\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}$, and $\Bbb C\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i\end{pmatrix}$. **How do I compute them?**

I tried to find the eigenvectors of   $$ \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & - \sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and I hoped to find they were $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i\end{pmatrix}$ but the eigenvalues depend on $\phi$, and the computation of the eigenvectors gets cumbersome and dependent on $\phi$, so I couldn't find what I expected.

Comment: @K02 The exercise does not say specify so :( , I thought I had to consider the Lie group complex, because we are acting on $\Bbb C^2$? To which case does your answer refer to? And how will it change in the other case?

Comment: You proved in your previous post that a commutative group only has $1$-dimensional irreducible representations, and this group is commutative.  To find the decomposition into eigenspaces all you need to do is diagonalize $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ which is the infinitesimal generator of the group.  That gives the two eigenvectors in the post.

Comment: @K02 $SO(n) = \{A \in M(n\Bbb ,R) | <Ax,Ay> = <x,y> for all x,y\in \Bbb R^n\}$, so real Lie groups

Comment: @ChadK So you got this matrix by evaluating $\phi =0$. Can the eigenspaces be computed from the matrix with any value of $\phi$? or even without asigning a value? And I should get the same result even if with more work?

Comment: @some_math_guy: No, I got the matrix by $\exp\left(\theta\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$.  Then one vector has eigenvalue $-i$ which exponentiates to $\exp(-i\theta)$ and the other vector has eigenvalue $i$ which exponentiates to $\exp(i\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the eigenvalues of the rotation depend on $\phi$, but the eigenvectors do not and their computation is quite straightforward. The characteristic polynomial of the rotation matrix $\rho$ is $X^2-2\cos\phi X+1$, its roots are the complex conjugate numbers $\def\ii{{\mathbf i}}\cos\phi\pm\ii\sin\phi$ of modulus $1$ (or a double real root in the exceptional case $\sin\phi=0$). The eigenspace for $\lambda=\cos\phi+{\mathbf i}\sin\phi$ is $\ker(\rho-\lambda I)=\ker(\left({-\ii\sin\phi\atop\sin\phi}~{-\sin\phi\atop\ii\sin\phi}\right))=\ker(\left({-\ii\atop1}~{-1\atop\ii}\right))$ which is spanned by $1\choose-\ii$, and similarly the eigenspace for $\lambda=\cos\phi-{\mathbf i}\sin\phi$ is spanned by $1\choose\ii$.

Comment: Are the eigenspaces the invariant subspaces? If yes, why? The invariant subspaces are those W sucht that  $\pi(g)W \subset W,  \forall g \in G$

Comment: Well yes. An eigenspace for $\phi$ is certainly a $\phi$-stable subspace, a subspace $V$ with $\phi(V)\subseteq{V}$. Here we have common eigenspaces for all $\phi=\pi(g)$ simultaneously, so invariant subspaces for$~\pi$.