# The natural representation of the real group $G=SO(2)$ on $V=\Bbb R^2$ is irreducible.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

> Prove that the natural representation of the real group $G=SO(2)$ on $V=\Bbb R^2$ is irreducible.

This is the followed up from this question
[The natural representation of $G=SO(2)$ on $V=\Bbb C^2$ is not irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818098/the-natural-representation-of-g-so2-on-v-bbb-c2-is-not-irreducible?noredirect=1#comment10253351_4818098)
I proved the following fact which may be useful:

**Proposition**: Let $G$ a commutative Lie group and $(\pi, V)$ a finite-dim unitary representation of $G$.

1. $\pi$ is irreducible iff ${\rm dim}\, V = 1$
2. There exist mutually orthogonal onedimensional invariant linear subspaces $V_1,..., V_n$ of $V  $ such that $V = V_1 \oplus · · · \oplus V_n$.
3. The natural representation of $SO(2)$ on $\Bbb C^2$ is not irreducible.

**My attempt:**
The natural representation of $ G=SO(2)$ consisting of matrices with real entries on $V=\Bbb R^2$ is given by:

$$\pi(g):V\to V: v\mapsto gv $$

**Question 1:**
I am not sure why the proof in 3. breaks down? It seems like I can state pretty much the same things.

I can verify the hypotheses of the propositon above:

- $G=SO(2)$ is a commutative Lie group.
- The representation $(V,\pi)$ is finite-dimensional  because $\Bbb R^2$ is finite-dimensional
- The representation $(V,\pi)$ is unitary  because rotations preserve the scalar product on $\Bbb R^2$

Then I can use 1. in the proposition to say that because the dim $V=2 \neq 1$ as a $\Bbb R$-vector space, $\pi$ is not irreducible, which is giving the opposite of what I want to prove. So there must be some step that is not valid anymore

**Question 2:** How do I prove it then?

Assume that the natural representation is not  irreducible, then 1. implies that the ${\rm dim}\, V\neq 1$.  This is obvious, so it does not seem to help

Comment: A unitary representation requires that the representation space is a vector space over the complex numbers, which $\Bbb{R}^2$ is not. Thus, you cannot use $(a)$. This is not a minor annoyance, it is in fact the crux of the problem.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Did yo mean SU(n)? But that is a different group, isn't it? and su(n) its Lie algebra?

Answer (score 1):

A unitary representation requires that the representation space is a vector space over the complex numbers, which $\Bbb{R}^2$ is not. Thus, you cannot use $(a)$. This is not a minor annoyance, it is in fact the crux of the problem.

The fact that you are not guaranteed to be able to solve every polynomial means that you are not ensured enough eigenvalues. In fact, you will find that almost no element of $\text{SO}(2)$ has real eigenvalues, and so the representation has no invariant one-dimensional subspace. Since the proper subspaces are one-dim. subspaces, the representation is irreducible.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I was a bit hasty. Though it is not hard to give such a statement meaning: we can think of $\text{SO}(2)$ as a family of operators, and as they are commuting, if one of the elements is diagonalizable with different eigenvalues, they are all diagonalizable. So saying $\text{SO}(2)$ has no eigenvalues means it has no non-scalar matrix with any eigenvalues (here using that we are in dimension $2$).

Comment: Could you elaborate how do you get to  "the representation has no invariant one-dimensional subspaces", I don't see what the conection with the eigenvalues is.

Comment: @some_math_guy: Let $v$ and element of a one-dimensional invariant subspace $V$. Since this subspace is one-dimensional every element in that subspace is of the form $\lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Being one-dimensional there is no room for other elements. Now let $g \in SO(2)$. Then, by virtue of the space $V$ being invariant, we know that $gv$ lives somewhere in $V$ so that $gv = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda$. But here we recognize the definition of eigenvector. In other words: if $v$ lives in a 1D invariant subspace then $v$ is an eigenvector for every $g \in SO(2)$.